# Question on definition of a cover and results with compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

My professor defines a cover of $A$ to be a collection of sets whose union is equal to $A$. I am used to this being instead a superset of $A$.

Doesn't this lead to contradictions?

Then, there can be no open cover equal to a set like $[0,\infty)$.

Therefore, vacuously, $[0,\infty)$ is compact as it has no open cover.

This is a contradiction.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, $[0,\infty)$ has an open cover, such as $\{[0,1)\}\cup \{(n,n+2) : n=0,1,2,\cdots\}$.

Comment: He's talking about open subsets of $A$, by which he means _relatively_ open subsets.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I've gotten no feedback at all for my answer (upvoted indicate people agree, but even a comment would be good, I'm at the point still where I like my answers confirmed and lack that confidence that comes with time, I don't suppose you can take a look?)

Comment: @AlecTeal Your answer is certainly correct - now you can sleep tonight. What gets upvoted and downvoted is one of those mysteries we were not meant to understand...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich that's all I wanted to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

No it does not lead to contradictions, see this page: [covering](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Covering) for information. Notice the **alternative definition** section

When you say a set is compact, you are imbuing it with the [subspace topology](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Subspace_topology) which will "cut off" any overlap anyway.

You can see the proof with [this lemma](http://www.maths.kisogo.com/index.php?title=Compactness#Lemma_for_a_set_being_compact)

---

Just to clarify the important part of the proof is:

> $(Y,\mathcal{J}_\text{subspace})$ is compact $\implies$ every covering of Y by sets open in X contains a finite subcovering

Comment: Not sure why I've not gotten at least one upvote. the linked lemma shows that $Y$ is compact with the subspace topology $\iff$ every covering by sets open in $X$ contains a finite subcover....

Comment: Downvoter, any reason?